# Why is this SVG's width not set with ng-attr-width?

Tags: angularjs, svg

I have a very simple web page to try to isolate an ng binding I do not understand:

```
<html ng-app="AngularSVGTestApp">
<head>
    <title>Angular SVG Test</title>
    <style>
        svg {
            background-color: aqua;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <div ng-cloak>
        <svg ng-show="mainCtrl.svg.show"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             baseProfile="full"
             version="1.1"
             ng-attr-width="mainCtrl.svg.width"
             ng-attr-height="mainCtrl.svg.height">
        </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('AngularSVGTestApp', [])
                .controller('MainCtrl', ['$http', function ($http) {
                    var self = this;
                    self.svg = {
                        show: true,
                        width: 400,
                        height: 400
                    };
                }]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

([Or fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/6tvpx21f/).)

I would expect the SVG to have width and height of 400 as set by `ng-attr-width="mainCtrl.svg.width"` and `ng-attr-height="mainCtrl.svg.height"` from the values in the model.

But they are not. When I use the browser's development tools to inspect the SVG element its size is 1054 x 931 (full-screen in Chrome), 1520 x 281.6 (full screen in IE), or 300 x 150 (in [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/6tvpx21f/))

Why? How do I bind the width and height of an SVG from AngularJS?

Comment: use ng-style it will work..

Comment: Don't know whether this helps you, but it works with `ng-style="{height: mainCtrl.svg.height, width: mainCtrl.svg.width}"`

Comment: Thanks for that - if you swap your comments to answers I'll accept one (especially if you can explain why my approach doesn't work). That leads me to [a follow-on question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28094052/575530). N.B. I'm using AngularJS v1.3.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT to front:** My original answer was incorrect - `ngAttrX` *does* works for an attribute X (such as `Width`). The reason it did not work in the original question was that the interpolation braces were missing (i.e. should have been `ng-attr-width="{{mainCtrl.svg.width}}"`).

Sorry about that.

---

`ngStyle` can be used to set the width and height, as comments suggest. I'm writing this answer more to try to help explain how this works (and why your `ng-attr-width` does not), and perhaps remove some of the "magic" from `ngStyle`.

`ngStyle` is itself a [directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L3). It adds a `$watchCollection` on the `ng-style` attribute and simply adds css rules based on this.

There is <strike>no</strike> directive for `ngAttrWidth`, but if you want one then you could make one fairly simply by linking `$watch` to the relevant attribute to modify the element. This might be more relevant for SVG attributes which cannot be taken from CSS (such as `path`).

**EDIT:**

I was wrong about `ng-attr-width`, Angular does have logic in place to modify attributes for any `ng-attr`-prefixed attributes. This works well if you always know that this directive will be provided the same attributes.

If you do not know exactly which attributes will be provided, creating a directive is still an option. Here is your pictures example working with your style collection (directive code mostly copied and adapted from Angular's [ngStyle directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngStyle.js#L3)): http://jsfiddle.net/n7fq3oy2/3/

Comment: Thanks - that helps. I am perplexed by your statement "ngAttrWidth" though, as I thought the `ng-attr-` prefix could be used for attributes without their own directives. Following [maxisam's answer to my follow on question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28094211/575530) I tried putting double curlies around the `ng-attr-width` and `ng-attr-height` and that fixed it (as you can see in this [fiddle revision](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/6tvpx21f/3/)).

Comment: Ahhh, you're right, there is some magic for the `ng-attr` prefix. Updated the answer to include that, as well as an example of adding an svg-attrs directive to modify subsets of these.

Comment: Wonderful! I've added in the double curlies so [all three bullfinches show](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/n7fq3oy2/2/). Your directive example is really useful, thanks.

Comment: Do you understand why `ng-attr-width` requires double curlies but `ng-show` or `ng-style` do not?

Comment: It's based on how the attributes are watched in the directives. `ngShow` and `ngStyle` use code that looks a bit like `scope.$watch(attr.ngShow, someFn);`. On the other hand, directives created for `ngAttr` do things a bit differently, and this is where things get a little complex and we have to dive pretty deep into the Angular code to understand it, they `$watch` the interpolated `value` itself rather than watching `attr[name]` (unless that name happens to be "class"): https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/cf17c6af475eace31cf52944afd8e10d3afcf6c0/src/ng/compile.js#L1106

Comment: In other words: it's an arbitrary decision that the Angular team seems to have made around AngularJS 1.1.4